Symfony ParamConverter to MapEntity
I am trying to upgrade my symfony application from version 5.4 to 6.4, as Sensio Bundle is abandoned i need to use attribute instead of annotation , how can i convert paramcoverter annotation to attribute, below is the code
class QuoteDataController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/data/quote/list", name="data_quote_list")
     * @ParamConverter("query", class="App:ListQuery")
     */
    public function dataQuoteList(ListQuery $query, SessionInterface $session): JsonResponse
    {
        try {
            /** @var Contact $user */
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $session->set('QuoteQuery', $query);
            $repo = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(Quote::class);

            $payloads = $repo->loadRecords($query, $user);

            return new JsonResponse([
                'total' => empty($payloads) ? 0 : $payloads[0]->getMeta()['found'],
                'rows' => $repo->tableise($payloads),
            ]);
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            // echo $e;

            return new JsonResponse([
                'total' => 0,
                'rows' => [],
            ]);
        }
    }
}


it seems like old paramconverter has a custom paramconverter class, old developer worked on that , i am new to this project.below is the code for custom paramconverter, which accepts multiple requests data. below is the code
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\ParamConverter;

use App\Entity\ListQuery;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Throwable;

class ListQueryConverter implements ParamConverterInterface
{
    public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration): bool
    {
        $query = new ListQuery(
            $request->query->get('search'),
            $request->query->getInt('offset') ?? 0,
            null === $request->query->get('limit') ? 5 : $request->query->getInt('limit'),
            $request->query->get('sort') ?? '',
            $this->determineSortOrder($request->query->get('order')),
            $this->setFilter($request->query->get('filter'))
        );

        $request->attributes->set($configuration->getName(), $query);

        return true;
    }

    public function supports(ParamConverter $configuration): bool
    {
        return 'App:ListQuery' === $configuration->getClass();
    }

    private function determineSortOrder(?string $order): string
    {
        if (ListQuery::SORT_ASCENDING === strtoupper($order)) {
            return ListQuery::SORT_ASCENDING;
        }

        return ListQuery::SORT_DESCENDING;
    }

    private function setFilter(?string $json): array
    {
        if (null === $json) {
            return [];
        }

        try {
            return json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
        } catch (Throwable $exception) {
            return [];
        }
    }
}

I tried the below code , but it is not working as expected
 #[Route('/data/quote/list', name: 'data_quote_list')]
 #[Entity('query', class: ListQuery::class)] ```



use https://github.com/rectorphp/rector it will do everything automatically.
